# I want to use BufferedReader more than once SOCKET

Tags: java, sockets

My project is a client/server program. The client opens the connection and makes the requests for console until the user enters "exit". The first time I get the correct response. For example:

```
command: get oscar
response server: value: moncayo
```

If I want to do more than one request, the BufferedReader always stuck with the first command request. I don't know what's wrong.

Client:

```
clientSocket = createSocket("127.0.0.1", 9990);
//clientSocket = createSocket(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
System.out.println("Connect with the server.");
inputClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

//Now we need to read the input of the user
do{
    try {
        dataServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        //Read input of the user
        System.out.print("command: ");
        command = inputClient.readLine() +"\n";
        manipulateCommand(command, dataServer);
        System.out.println("Message Delivered.");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}while(!command.equals("exit"));
```

SERVER:

```
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Accepted Client : ID - " + clientID + " : Address - "
            + clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostName());
    try {
        char [] x = {};
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
        while (isRunning) {
            if((inputclient  = in.readLine())!= null){
                System.out.println("Client Says :" + inputclient+"\n");
            }
```

manipulateCommand:

```
public static void manipulateCommand(String command, DataOutputStream dataServer){
    try {

        String type = null, key = null,value = null, message = null, result =null;
        StringTokenizer subString = new StringTokenizer(command);
            switch(subString.nextToken()){
                case "get":
                    type = "get";
                    key = subString.nextToken();
                    value= "";
                    break;
                case "set":
                    type = "set";
                    key = subString.nextToken();
                    value= subString.nextToken();
                    break;
                case "del":
                    type = "del";
                    key = subString.nextToken();
                    value= "";
                    break;
                case "list":
                    type = "list";
                    key="";
                    value="";
                    break;
                case "exit":
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        result = KVUtil.getXMLString(type, key, value,true);
        dataServer.writeBytes(result +"\n");
        dataServer.flush();
        //dataServer.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error handling the input command");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the implementation of `manipulateCommand()`?

Comment: Now you can check the implementation of manipulateCommand()

Comment: Your read loop is incorrect. If it encounters `null` it should exit the loop. The usual way of writing it is `while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)`. You should create the `DataOutputStream` outside the loop, not every time, but in fact you should be using a `BufferedWriter`, not a `DataInputStream`, as you are using a `Reader` at the peer. I don't see anything here that would cause your server to behave as described.

Comment: I check your suggestions and I still face this problem :c . I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Another problem: when you catch an exception, don't just print some aimless message of your own devising. Print the exception, preferably the stack trace. I'm wondering whether you're getting a runtime exception here, for example a `NullPointerException` inside `KVUtil.getXMLString()`, whatever that is.